# What is the correct designpattern for UI?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am making a small app for loading data from an external device. It uses a DLL.

I want to make the app running in one window. With the menu it should be possible to bring up the correct state of UI. I dont want to use dialogs or seperate windows.

My idea is to use a state variable and have the WM_PAINT message handle the different content of the windows (createwindowEx for different text and button items i.e.).

Is this the correct way of doing so? I have searched the internet, read Programming Windows and searched stackoverflow and could not find a simple example. It is always using different windows with dedicated winproc functions. It feels like i dont need that...

Can someone help me with a direction or small example/link ?

thx

EDIT:
I enclose the code that i have so far now. Can someone have a look on that, Thx.

```
#if defined _MSC_VER || defined __BORLANDC__
#define OEMRESOURCE
#endif

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#include <windows.h>  //include all the basics
#include <tchar.h>    //string and other mapping macros
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "hrmcom.h"
#include "resource.h"

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> ustring;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

inline int ErrMsg(const ustring&);
bool CreateChild(HWND);
bool CreateChildScreen(HWND);

ustring classname = TEXT("MAINWND");
ustring childname = TEXT("CHILDWND");

HWND    hwndChild[3], hwndCtrl[CTRNUM];

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pStr, int nCmd)
{
WNDCLASSEX wcx = { 0 };  

wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcx.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;             
wcx.hInstance = hInst;   
wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
wcx.hCursor = reinterpret_cast<HCURSOR>(LoadImage(0, IDC_ARROW,
    IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED));
wcx.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
wcx.lpszClassName = classname.c_str();

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
{
    ErrMsg(_T("Failed to register wnd class"));
    return -1;
}
wcx.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;
wcx.cbWndExtra = sizeof (long);
wcx.hIcon = NULL;
wcx.lpszClassName = childname.c_str();

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
{
    ErrMsg(_T("Failed to register wnd class"));
    return -1;
}

HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU));

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,                     
    classname.c_str(),       
    TEXT("Polar Loader"),      
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,     
    400, 200, 600, 300,       
    0,                     
    hMenu,                   
    hInst,                  
    0);                      
if (!hwnd)
{
    ErrMsg(TEXT("Failed to create wnd"));
    return -1;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmd);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)>0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
 }

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    //Create the Childwindows
    if (!CreateChild(hwnd))
    {
        ErrMsg(TEXT("Failed to create Childwindows"));
        return -1;
    }
    //Create controls of the Childwindows 
    if (!CreateChildScreen(hwnd))
    {
        ErrMsg(TEXT("Failed to create Conrols of Childwindows"));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDM_Acc:
        ShowWindow(hwndChild[0], SW_SHOW);
        return 0;
    case IDM_Con:
    case IDM_Help:
    case IDM_Log:
    case IDM_Pol:
    case IDM_Trans:
        ShowWindow(hwndChild[0], SW_HIDE);
        return 0;       
    }

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);    //signal end of application
    return 0;
default:
    //let system deal with msg
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
 }
 LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
switch (uMsg)
{   
case WM_CREATE:
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, 0, 0);      
    return 0;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case ID_CTRL+5:         
        MessageBeep(0);
        return 0;
    }
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
 }


 inline int ErrMsg(const ustring& s)
 {
return MessageBox(0, s.c_str(), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
 }


 bool CreateChild(HWND hwnd)
 {
static int x;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    hwndChild[x] = CreateWindowEx(0, childname.c_str(), NULL,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 600, 300,
        hwnd, (HMENU)x,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);
    if (!hwndChild[x]) return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
 }

 bool CreateChildScreen(HWND hwnd)
 {
LPCWSTR lpType[CTRNUM] = { TEXT("static"), TEXT("edit"), TEXT("edit"), TEXT("static"), TEXT("static"), TEXT("button") };
LPCWSTR lpName[CTRNUM] = { TEXT("Log on to Gedysan Training App:"), TEXT(""), TEXT(""), TEXT("Username:"), TEXT("Password:"), TEXT("Log on") };
DWORD dStyle[CTRNUM] = { WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER | ES_PASSWORD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT
};
RECT rc[CTRNUM] = { { 15, 10, 400, 25 }, { 100, 40, 150, 25 }, { 100, 70, 150, 25 }, { 15, 45, 70, 25 }, { 15, 75, 70, 25 }, { 15, 110, 70, 25 } };
int iChildNum[CTRNUM] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
static int x;
for (x = 0; x < CTRNUM; x++)
{
    RECT x1 = rc[x];
    hwndCtrl[x] = CreateWindowEx(0, lpType[x], lpName[x], dStyle[x],
        x1.left, x1.top, x1.right, x1.bottom,
        hwndChild[iChildNum[0]], (HMENU)(ID_CTRL + x),
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 0);
    if (!hwndChild[x]) return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
 }
```

Comment: WM_PAINT is not correct place for CreateWindowEx. As for other parts of your question - they are not clear. If all program functions can be shown using one window, you can do this.

Comment: forgive me for my poor english... What I mean is that based on the selected menu a different UI should be presented. For example: Account settings, Input, Status reports, etc. I want that all in one window.

Comment: In this case you can use tab control. Create dialog-based Win32 application: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227831/A-dialog-based-Win-C-program Then add tab control to the dialog template.

Comment: Thx Alex, i will have to look into that. I will google on tab control.

Comment: edited with code now

Comment: Don't reuse the same question, post new question for every specific problem you have.

Comment: i am not reusing, i promised to put the code belonging to this topic here

Answer (score 2):

With your proposed approach you will get a bunch of unrelated stuff all in the WM_PAINT handler, making a messy design. When a menu selection is made you get a message. Run code related to that menu command in that message handler.

If your UI is composed of controls then WM_PAINT is not involved at all: Those controls do their own painting. Your WM_PAINT handler should do any custom painting you need, and nothing else.

Comment: Thx for the answer Scott. Can it be done in the control messages and then swap child windows (with the controls as childs in it again). It is hard to find an example that shows this principle...

Comment: Yes that is the usual way to do it. The child windows are standard modeless dialogs. If you don't want them to look like dialogs then turn off their titlebar style and they will appear visually to be part of the main window.

Comment: I did some experimenting and I got it rudimentairy working. When i have time to finish it, i will edit the question with my version. Hopefully you would like to have a look at it then :-). I made a windowsclass for the main window and a windowclass for the 4 childs. The childs have their own winproc. The main winproc is for now just handling the menu messages and shows and hides the child windows.